# Magento 2 rest api get product's attributes options

Tags: product, product-attribute, custom-attributes, magento-2.1.7, rest-api

I would like to get more then one product's attributes options in one query
I have my url for one attribute option as follow:

> http://magento2.dev/rest/V1/products/attributes/size/options

The above I am receiving all the options for `size`, now the question is:

How do one get attribute options for `colour` in the same call?

e.g One could do http://magento2.dev/rest/V1/products/attributes/size|colour/options

passing parameters separated by pipe or comma whatever how can one do this in Magento 2?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found out how to get list options I was looking for, it's possible to get 
attributes groups with array with options like so:

> http://magento2.dev/rest/V1/products/attributes?&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_group_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=31

Where `31` is the attribute_group_id of custom attribute group `MISC`

Comment: Just to add you need admin rights to access this way

Answer (score 3):

Might be a little late but...

The following query returns options of MY_ATTR_CODE_1 and MY_ATTR_CODE_2.

```
products/attributes?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_code&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=MY_ATTR_CODE_1& searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][field]=attribute_code&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][value]=MY_ATTR_CODE_2&fields=items[attribute_code,options]
```

You can add as many attributes as you like this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think Magento2 doesn't allow to pass multiple options in this request.
You can use the only one option at a time. You can refer webapi.xml file of catalog module under vendor directory.

You can create custom API for it. Here is an example to create custom REST API in Magento2.
https://www.envisionecommerce.com/how-to-use-magento-2-rest-api/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It seems that Magento API isn't so robust yet

Comment: Perhaps there is another way what about GET attribute size and colour that belongs to an attribute group  like a custom attribute e.g "MISC" then it will have size, colour etc.. and get all options is there way can be done Magento?